# Родительские и дочерние формы

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть три формы:Form1-3. Form2 я сделал родительской по отношению к Form3. И теперь мне нужно,чтобы эта Form2,со вложенной Form3 стала дочерней к Form1.Но,как я понял,родительской может быть только одна форма. Когда я пытаюсь сделать родительской Form1,появляется следующая ошибка:"Формы контейнера MDI должны принадлежать верхнему уровню."Подскажите,пожалуйста,как можно решить эту проблему?

Вот таким образом устанавливаю отношение между формами:

```
Form2.IsMdiContainer = true;
Form3 = new Form3();
Form3.MdiParent = Form2;
```

Comment: О боги, зачем вам это? Пересмотрели Inception?

Comment: Сделай то же самое без использования MDI.